# $.parseJSON - uncaught SyntaxError - how to check for undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

I have the following jQuery function that's throwing an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` when the cookie `$.cookie('chk_ar')` is undefined.

```
function checkBgNoise() {
// check background noise option state,
// if true, click 'on' to activate
// then add classes and check checkboxes

if( $.cookie('bg-noise-state') === 'true' ) {
  $('#bg-noise-on').trigger('click');

  // check for bg-noise array cookie
  var chk_ar = $.cookie('chk_ar');

  // convert string to object
  chk_ar = $.parseJSON(chk_ar);

  // loop through and apply checks to matching sets
  $.each(chk_ar, function(index, value) {
    // add bg-noise class for activated areas
    $('.' + value).addClass('bg-noise');
    // check those areas
    $('input').filter('[data-at="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', true);
  });

} else if ( $.cookie('bg-noise-state') === 'false' ) {

  // remove classes when selecting 'off'
  var chk_ar = $.cookie('chk_ar');
  chk_ar = $.parseJSON(chk_ar);
  $.each(chk_ar, function(index, value) {
    // remove bg-noise added on toggling off noise
    $('.' + value).removeClass('bg-noise');
    // uncheck the boxes
    $('input').filter('[data-at="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', false);
  });      
};

}; // end function checkBgNoise
```

I'm still learning the javascript ropes, so it's entirely possible that there are some rather obvious mistakes in my approach. The code is generally functioning, but I'd like to get rid of the error if possible.

Searching the error code here on Stack Exchange and Google suggest that the problem is in the call to `$.parseJSON(chk_ar)`, which is at times undefined. Any ideas on how to remedy this? A simple `if` statement?

Comment: `if (chk_ar == "undefined") return;`

Comment: Thanks @Archer. And forgive my ignorance, but where would that go? At the very end of each `if statement`?

Comment: Put it straight after each time you try to assign a value to `chk_ar`.   I assume there's no point carrying on if it's undefined, so that will just drop out.

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't do the trick. I've applied it in multiple places, but no cigar. I've also tried wrapping the innards of the `checkBgNoise` function in `if (($.cookie('chk_ar')) != "undefined")`, but this doesn't do the trick, either. Perhaps it's not possible to nest if statements? (seems unlikely.)

Comment: Nested if statements (unfortunately) are perfectly legit and used often.  (I say unfortunately due to the amount of times I've had to untangle them after inexperienced developers have just kept adding the things unnecessarily! :p )

Comment: Most certainly. "When all you have is a hammer..." As I'm learning, I'm trying to stay away from them... *if* possible :) Too bad there isn't a javascript `unless` statement (there isn't, is there?).

Comment: You can say `if (this) { do that } else if (something else) { do another this) } else { if neither of them do this instead }`.  There are also switch statements to look at as well, but you use what suits your needs.

Comment: Ahh... many thanks. It's been a long day :)

Comment: We all start somewhere.  It doesn't seem that long ago that I was typing `10 PRINT "John is cool"` `20 GOTO 10`.  It doesn't seem that long ago because of senility though - it was over 30 years ago :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a slight modification so you get `chk_ar` at the top of the function and then exit if it's undefined.  Since both states require it then it makes sense to get and check at the top...

```
function checkBgNoise() {
    // get this here since both states need the value - exit if it's undefined
    var chk_ar = $.cookie('chk_ar');
    if (chk_ar == undefined) return;

    // check background noise option state,
    // if true, click 'on' to activate
    // then add classes and check checkboxes

    if( $.cookie('bg-noise-state') === 'true' ) {
        $('#bg-noise-on').trigger('click');

        // convert string to object
        chk_ar = $.parseJSON(chk_ar);

        // loop through and apply checks to matching sets
        $.each(chk_ar, function(index, value) {
            // add bg-noise class for activated areas
            $('.' + value).addClass('bg-noise');
            // check those areas
            $('input').filter('[data-at="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
    else if ( $.cookie('bg-noise-state') === 'false' ) {
        // remove classes when selecting 'off'
        chk_ar = $.parseJSON(chk_ar);
        $.each(chk_ar, function(index, value) {
            // remove bg-noise added on toggling off noise
            $('.' + value).removeClass('bg-noise');
            // uncheck the boxes
            $('input').filter('[data-at="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', false);
        });      
    };
} // end function checkBgNoise
```

Comment: Works! No more error :) I hadn't thought to simply check for the cookie at the beginning of the function... *certainly* much nicer than simply adding *another* if statement.